# implementing synchronization to get the proper threads output properly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, synchronization

Currently when I run the program, the threads are running at random. For example the current output is :

```
Global.sharedBuffer[0] = 2
Global.sharedBuffer[1] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[2] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[3] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[4] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[5] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[6] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[7] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[8] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[9] = 1
Global.sharedBuffer[10] = 2
Global.sharedBuffer[11] = 4
Global.sharedBuffer[12] = 3
```

What I want is from sharedBuffer 0 to 9 all 1's , then from 10 - 19 all 2's and etc. I added a synchronization block thinking it would do this, however, it just stopped it from context switching every time a thread was called. How do you go about implementing this?

CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class MyThreadExample2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   HelloThread ht1 = new HelloThread(1);
   HelloThread ht2 = new HelloThread(2);
   HelloThread ht3 = new HelloThread(3);
   HelloThread ht4 = new HelloThread(4);
   ht1.start();
   ht2.start();
   ht3.start();
   ht4.start();
   }
}

class Global {
    public static int[] sharedBuffer = new int[1000];
    public static int in = 0;
}


class HelloThread extends Thread {
    int threadID;

    HelloThread(int threadID) {
System.out.println("threadID:  " + threadID);
    this.threadID = threadID;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {



if((Global.in >= 0 || Global.in <= 99) && (this.threadID == 1))
       Global.sharedBuffer[Global.in] = this.threadID;

else if((Global.in >= 100 || Global.in <= 199) && (this.threadID == 2))
       Global.sharedBuffer[Global.in] = this.threadID;

else if((Global.in >= 200 || Global.in <= 299) && (this.threadID == 3))
       Global.sharedBuffer[Global.in] = this.threadID;

else if((Global.in >= 300 || Global.in <= 399) && (this.threadID == 4))
       Global.sharedBuffer[Global.in] = this.threadID;



System.out.println("Thread " + this.threadID + " has written " 
        + this.threadID + " to Global.sharedBuffer[" + Global.in + "]\n");


       Global.in++;
       }

    if (this.threadID == 4) 
    {
        try {this.sleep(2000L);
    } 
        catch (Throwable e) {e.printStackTrace();
    }

System.out.println("The final buffer is **************\n");
       for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    System.out.println("Global.sharedBuffer[" + i + "] = " + 
                            Global.sharedBuffer[i]);
       } // for
    } // if
   } // run




} // end Thread
```

Comment: Don't use a global `in` variable - all threads are updating it concurrently and it's one big data race condition. Just use a local index counter that starts at where it should start and ends where it should end.

Comment: If you want sequential execution why are you using threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-threading only works if you can formulate tasks which can be performed independently of others. You have to avoid shared variables and if you can’t avoid it, the access must be properly guarded, which usually implies limiting the concurrency of the thread execution.

For your task it is simple to formulate independent tasks as each thread shall write into a different region of the array:

```
public class ThreadingExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int numThread=4, chunkSize=10;
        int[] array=new int[numThread*chunkSize];
        Thread[] thread=new Thread[numThread];

        // create threads and define their jobs
        for(int t=0, p=0; t<numThread; t++, p+=chunkSize) {
            thread[t]=new Thread(new FillInJob(array, t, p, chunkSize));
        }

        // start the threads
        for(Thread t: thread) t.start();
        // now all running concurrently

        // wait for completion
        try {
            for(Thread t: thread) t.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError(ex);
        }

        // use result
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
class FillInJob implements Runnable {
    private final int[] targetArray;
    private final int myID, startIndex, endIndex;

    FillInJob(int[] target, int id, int start, int size) {
      targetArray=target;
      myID=id;
      startIndex=start;
      endIndex=start+size;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int ix=startIndex; ix<endIndex; ix++)
            targetArray[ix]=myID;
    }
}
```